# Uploading image files to subdomain

Tags: php

I have an admin subdomain set up:

> admin.mysite.co.uk

And a 'main' site:

> www.mysite.co.uk

On the admin site I want to upload images to the main site, so the upload scripts etc. exist on the *sub*domain yet the file is uploaded to the main domain.

This code works OK for uploads to the *admin* subdomain:

```
$target_file = 'images/carousel/' . basename($_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

So, what path do I drop in here:

```
$target_file = 'images/carousel/' . basename($_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]);
```

To get it to upload the main domain ?

Is this even possible ?

Comment: You need to use absolute path. Your subdomain uses a folder on the same server. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320785/destination-path-for-move-uploaded-file-in-php

Comment: another question for your reference that says the same thing @valicu2000 said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164828/check-upload-images-to-domain-folder-from-subdomain

Comment: Add that as an answer @valicu2000 and I'll tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute path. Your subdomain uses a folder on the same server. Please see: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8320785/

Answer (score 0):

Using the move_uploaded_file function you decide where the file is saved. Depending on how you have configured your server; the only thing you need to do is move the files to the correct folder.